# Zapier WebHook Get Command returns data but not all per data break

Tags: zapier

When I use Webhooks in Zapier for a get command I am able to retrieve the data that I need, however it is delineated by breaks.  Therefore, in the following Zapier step, I can only retrieve one record and not all the records.

Any assistance in coding would be greatly appreciated.

screen grab from Postman:

[image]